# Publishing from HTML to RPubs not an option anymore?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to publish from an RMarkdown-generated HTML page to RPubs. However, when I click "Publish", there is no RPubs option, just RStudio Connect. A similar problem to this user, and with pictures of what it should look like: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3389 and https://community.rstudio.com/t/the-rpubs-bottom-disappeared/55404/3.

RStudio version 1.3.1056.

I have already tried following the suggestions in these links, as well as updating knitr, RStudio (previous version was a 1.2.xx), restarting RStudio, and rebooting my Mac. This doesn't seem to be a problem for everyone, as I noticed on the RPubs site that people are still uploading as of ~40m ago.

Any help greatly appreciated, as the RPubs [get-started page](https://rpubs.com/about/getting-started) does not offer much assistance.

[As mentioned in the attached links, there should be an RPubs option here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDwPc.png)

Answer (score 3):

Just solved the problem--make sure not to have `self_contained: false` in the header of the .RMD file.